# Can i install windows application on windows 8 tab?

Tags: windows, windows-8, tablet

Can i install windows application on windows 8 tab? Like office ,games etc. Or it support only apps from windows store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a Windows RT tab, you are restricted to installing Windows 8 apps through the Windows Store.

If it's a Windows 8 tab, you can install any Windows application that you could install on Windows 7, in addition to Windows 8 apps through the Windows Store.

Comment: I have found this term everywhere. What eaxactly RT Tabs means? Cant we reinstall our windows version on RT tabs?

Comment: @Serjas, see here: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-33642_7-57454524-292/just-what-is-windows-rt-anyway-faq/

Comment: @Serjas, Windows RT is in many ways the equivalent of iOS for the iPad, in that it comes preinstalled on all devices and is part of an ecosystem controlled by the OS vendor (Microsoft in this case). Unlike MacOS (which cannot run iOS apps), Windows 8 will be able to run all apps that Windows RT can run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it supports apps from only windos store, but don't worry about applications like office, u will be able to install them.